# vc_redist.x86.exe Setup Failed: 0x80240017 Unspecified error

Tags: windows-7, installation, visual-c++, redistributable

[An installer](https://github.com/dokan-dev/dokany/releases/tag/v0.8.0) told me I need to first install `Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013` and gave the link https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Unfortunately that link, after a few selection steps, does not download anything, so I unfortunately had to get the file (`vc_redist.x86.exe`) from [SoftPedia](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Components-Libraries/Microsoft-Visual-C-Redistributable-Package.shtml) (even though I don't like to get files from unofficial sites).

Anyway, when I attempt to install that `vc_redist.x86.exe` on Windows 7 Professional 32 bit, I get this error:

[image: vc_redist.x86.exe Setup Failed 0x80240017 Unspecified error]

Here is the log file:

```
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:39]i001: Burn v3.7.3813.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\win7pro32bit\Downloads\vc_redist.x86.exe, cmdline: '-burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{666EA247-11E9-45A0-9D2B-9A7A9C20DE60} {C41C0D3B-3441-414E-8CCD-D5E0E8CB8745} 3584'
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\WIN7PR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20150929155640.log'
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\win7pro32bit\Downloads\vc_redist.x86.exe'
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\win7pro32bit\Downloads\'
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:40]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) - 14.0.23026'
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:40]i100: Detect begin, 10 packages
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:40]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKey, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:40]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:40]i000: Setting numeric variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 0
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:41]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:41]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:41]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:41]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:41]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:41]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:41]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:41]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:41]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:41]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:41]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:41]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:41]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:41]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:41]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:41]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:41]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:41]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:41]i052: Condition 'VersionNT >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT = v5.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 2) OR (VersionNT = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to true.
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:41]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i200: Plan begin, 10 packages, action: Install
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86' to value 'C:\Users\WIN7PR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20150929155640_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86_rollback.log'
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86' to value 'C:\Users\WIN7PR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20150929155640_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86.log'
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86' to value 'C:\Users\WIN7PR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20150929155640_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86_rollback.log'
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86' to value 'C:\Users\WIN7PR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20150929155640_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86.log'
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x86
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x64
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x86
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x64
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x86
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x64
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x86
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x64
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: None
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:56:44]i300: Apply begin
[0E00:0BA0][2015-09-29T15:56:45]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0E00:0BA0][2015-09-29T15:57:42]i361: Created a system restore point.
[0E00:0BA0][2015-09-29T15:57:42]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[0E00:0BA0][2015-09-29T15:57:43]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\WIN7PR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}\.be\VC_redist.x86.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}\VC_redist.x86.exe'
[0E00:0BA0][2015-09-29T15:57:43]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, version: 14.0.23026.0
[0E00:0BA0][2015-09-29T15:57:43]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0E00:0D3C][2015-09-29T15:57:49]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86.
[0E00:0D3C][2015-09-29T15:57:49]i305: Verified acquired payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{A2563E55-3BEC-3828-8D67-E5E8B9E8B675}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86\vc_runtimeMinimum_x86.msi.
[0E00:0D3C][2015-09-29T15:57:49]i304: Verified existing payload: cab54A5CABBE7274D8A22EB58060AAB7623 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab54A5CABBE7274D8A22EB58060AAB7623.
[0E00:0D3C][2015-09-29T15:57:49]i305: Verified acquired payload: cab54A5CABBE7274D8A22EB58060AAB7623 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab54A5CABBE7274D8A22EB58060AAB7623, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{A2563E55-3BEC-3828-8D67-E5E8B9E8B675}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86\cab1.cab.
[0E00:0D3C][2015-09-29T15:57:49]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeAdditional_x86.
[0E00:0D3C][2015-09-29T15:57:49]i305: Verified acquired payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{BE960C1C-7BAD-3DE6-8B1A-2616FE532845}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_x86\vc_runtimeAdditional_x86.msi.
[0E00:0D3C][2015-09-29T15:57:49]i304: Verified existing payload: cabB3E1576D1FEFBB979E13B1A5379E0B16 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cabB3E1576D1FEFBB979E13B1A5379E0B16.
[0E00:0D3C][2015-09-29T15:57:49]i305: Verified acquired payload: cabB3E1576D1FEFBB979E13B1A5379E0B16 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cabB3E1576D1FEFBB979E13B1A5379E0B16, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{BE960C1C-7BAD-3DE6-8B1A-2616FE532845}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_x86\cab1.cab.
[0E00:0D3C][2015-09-29T15:57:50]i304: Verified existing payload: Windows7_MSU_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Windows7_MSU_x86.
[0E00:0D3C][2015-09-29T15:57:50]i305: Verified acquired payload: Windows7_MSU_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Windows7_MSU_x86, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\D4036846864773E3D647F421DFE7F6CA536E307B\packages\Patch\x86\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x86.msu.
[0E00:0BA0][2015-09-29T15:57:50]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{A2563E55-3BEC-3828-8D67-E5E8B9E8B675}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86\vc_runtimeMinimum_x86.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:58:03]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0E00:0BA0][2015-09-29T15:58:03]i325: Registering dependency: {74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeMinimumVSU_x86,v14, package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86
[0E00:0BA0][2015-09-29T15:58:03]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{BE960C1C-7BAD-3DE6-8B1A-2616FE532845}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_x86\vc_runtimeAdditional_x86.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:58:09]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0E00:0BA0][2015-09-29T15:58:09]i325: Registering dependency: {74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditionalVSU_x86,v14, package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86
[0E00:0BA0][2015-09-29T15:58:09]i301: Applying execute package: Windows7_MSU_x86, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\D4036846864773E3D647F421DFE7F6CA536E307B\packages\Patch\x86\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x86.msu, arguments: '"C:\Windows\system32\wusa.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\D4036846864773E3D647F421DFE7F6CA536E307B\packages\Patch\x86\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x86.msu" /quiet /norestart'
[0E00:0BA0][2015-09-29T15:58:38]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:58:38]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:58:38]i319: Applied execute package: Windows7_MSU_x86, result: 0x80240017, restart: None
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:58:38]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[0E00:0BA0][2015-09-29T15:58:38]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[0E00:0BA0][2015-09-29T15:58:38]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[06F0:0A94][2015-09-29T15:58:38]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80240017, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: After a couple of attempts (the first few failed) I was able to download from  https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784 using Firefox.

Comment: Your error could well be because you are trying to install the 2015 version instead of the 2013 version ...

Comment: @DavidPostill: How did you manage to download? I keep pressing "Try again" but it does not seem to do anything... Reloading the link does not work either. I tried Chrome, Firefox, and even IE, on Windows and Linux.

Comment: It is working for me if I go there via this page https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003 maybe it sets a cookie or something? If I use your link directly it doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Your tips solved the problem, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 8):

I installed Windows 7 Service Pack 1 per my post here: https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/464swn/microsoft_visual_c_2015_redistributable_setup/ and that resolved the error.

> - Installing SP1 allowed me to run the Visual C++ Redistributable successfully thereby placing the dependency api....dll and allowing my program to run.
> - I downloaded the .iso file for SP1 from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5842
> - Mounted and installed using: http://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/download/

Comment: @Abraxas - Additional information isn't required.  This answer does indeed identify the real reason for the author's problem.  **Windows v6.1 (Build 7600: Service Pack 0)**

Answer (score 7):

The trick for the download was to NOT click on the big red "Try again" button, and instead click the small "Click here" link of the individual file.

That `vc_redist.x86.exe` installs successfully:

[image]

Thanks @DavidPostill!

Answer (score -1):

[image: https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=53840]

Download by clicking on `click here to download manually` on `Choose the files that didnt download` page.

OR

Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 links:

64 bit : [vc_redist.x64.exe](https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/A/A/6AA4EDFF-645B-48C5-81CC-ED5963AEAD48/vc_redist.x64.exe)

32 bit : 
[vc_redist.x86.exe](https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/A/A/6AA4EDFF-645B-48C5-81CC-ED5963AEAD48/vc_redist.x86.exe)

Comment: Author needed to install **Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013** not **Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2015**